# User interface design with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I would like to make UI like in link that i have provided below. How is it possible with Bootstrap or with basic html table?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jviUL.jpg

Comment: its definitely possible. but you gota try it yourself. we fix code here, not write them for you.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This layout can be created in two rows - one for the first 4 elements in the first column + the big element, and another one for the rest 4 small elements. A row in Bootstrap is basically a `<div class="row">`

Inside the first row, there must be 2 columns with different widths (in percents). The first one could be `<div class="col-xs-3">`, while the second one could be `<div class="col-xs-9">`.

*[NOTE]: The sum of the numbers in `col-xs-3` and `col-xs-9` should be equal to **12**.*

The same applies to the second row. There are 4 elements, so it would be easy to calculate:

`12 / 4 = 3` - for each element inside that row, a `<div class="col-xs-3">` should be used.

---

The resulting HTML would look like this:

```
<div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thx. This example was brilliant. It solved my problem.

Comment: @user2088073, please accept this as the right answer if it really helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```